# cocoa could not connect action

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I've been fiddling with Objective-C + Cocoa and writing a fairly simple Cocoa application. Then I encountered a runtime error that has no effect on my program execution:

> Could not connect the action textField: to target of class BarController

I'm experimenting with pulling some of the windows out of MainMenu.xib and loading them with separate controllers and xib files.

In one window within a new xib I've created a Text Field and linked it to an IBOutlet NSTextField (textField) in a new NSWindowController subclass. It works and I am able to use textField to update the contents of the Text Field.

I am curious why I am getting the above runtime error and I'm hoping that understanding it will clear up some of the magic around the UI construction process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not much magic with plain `IBOutlets`, really - the fun starts when using Bindings or actions sent to some yet unknown target via First Responder and the responder chain :-)

Regarding your error:
**Sounds like you've connected an outlet to a target that doesn't exist in your target class?**

You might have established a connection to a property in `File Owner` (or some other proxy object) at some point where the owner's class was e.g. `MyAppDelegate`.
Then you've moved the window (or other object containing the outlet) to some other .xib and now the owner's class is `MyWindowController` that doesn't have a property of the same name you've connected your outlet to - and voila, the runtime won't be able to establish the connection for your outlet at runtime.

Just double-check your outlets in the Interface Editor, there's probably already some kind of warning message displayed next to outlets that look fishy.

Delete or reassign them and you're done.

Comment: Thanks! I deleted/recreated the objects and noticed that I still need an IBAction method (even though the Text Field has editable disabled!). So it was complaining that I had no method for that and there was no runtime problem noticeable.

Comment: Yeah, these kinds of problems don't really show up at runtime (at least with the default settings/flags/env variables) unfortunately.